# Drop XMPP message in eJabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to filter message in eJabberd. I get messages with type service, process it, and then drop it.

My approach:I just set return packet to `<query xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"><query>`. Is there a better way to drop packet?

```
on_filter_packet({From, To, XML} = Packet) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("on_beanstalkd ~p~n", [Packet]),
    Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"type">>, XML),
    DataTag = xml:get_subtag(XML, <<"data">>), 

    case Type =:= <<"service">> of
    true -> 
        JSON = xml:get_tag_cdata(xml:get_subtag(XML, <<"body">>)),
        {inserted, ID} = beanstalk:put(BeanstalkdPid, JSON),
        Return = #xmlel{name = <<"query">>, attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>, <<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}]};
    false ->
        Return = Packet
    end,   
    Return.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return the atom `drop`, and ejabberd will drop the packet.